# How to remove or disable firebase accound with uid in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am building an admin panel in flutter.
i want to implement an feature that **super admin can delete or disable
an existing users account.**

anybody know how to do this,
iam using flutter `2.8`
i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In the Flutter SDK (and other client-side SDKs) there is only the option to delete the currently signed-in user. There is no way to delete or disable another user's account by their UID, as that would introduce a significant security risk.

The option to [delete a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) or [disable them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) by their UID *does* exist in the Admin SDKs, which are SDKs that are designed to run in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run. This type of SDK cannot be used in your Flutter (or other client-side) app.

If you're trying to build application admin logic into a Flutter application, you'll usually split that in two parts:

1. Build a custom back-end API (on your own server or through Cloud Functions/Cloud Run) where you have an endpoint for each feature you need. In there, you'll need to ensure that the user that calls your custom API is authorized to do so, for example by checking their UID against a known list, or checking for a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).
2. Then you build the Flutter UI on top of this custom UI, passing your ID token to the custom API so that it can check whether the caller is authorized to delete/disable the user (as otherwise you'll be creating the same security risk I mentioned earlier).

I recommend also checking this answer that I just gave on a different, but related, question: [Password Authentication with Vaadin Flow and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70987803/password-authentication-with-vaadin-flow-and-firebase/70988424#70988424)

Comment: Is it possible to manage this problem by creating a simple node js project to remove an account and connect the backend project with flutter.

Comment: If that simple node js project is what I describe in #1, then that's indeed the approach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First add [firebase_admin package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admin) to your project.

Then you need to add your firebase project into it.

```
var app = FirebaseAdmin.instance.initializeApp(AppOptions(
credential: ServiceAccountCredential('service-account.json'),
```

Then you can use this following code:

```
Future<void> deleteUser(String uid) async {
   await app.auth().deleteAccount(uid);
}
```

Comment: it only deletes the user currently logged in the app; i want remove any accounds in the database. that the admins can only do this action or the owner can only have acces to it

Comment: @Leskeboy Sorry for misunderstaning. I fixed the code, you can check it.

Comment: **The firbase admin admin plugin cant use with the version of firebase i have using** i am getting this error while adding this dependency  `Because firebase_auth >=3.3.6 depends on firebase_auth_web ^3.3.7 which depends on http_parser ^4.0.0, firebase_auth >=3.3.6 requires http_parser ^4.0.0.
And because firebase_admin <0.2.0-dev.0 depends on http ^0.12.0 which depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0, firebase_auth >=3.3.6 is incompatible with firebase_admin <0.2.0-dev.0.
So, because login_role depends on both firebase_admin ^0.1.4 and firebase_auth ^3.3.6, version solving failed.`