# Password Authentication with Vaadin Flow and Firebase

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, firebase-authentication, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I set up a Spring Boot project using https://start.spring.io including Spring Security and Vaadin. Then I set the Vaadin version to 22.0.4 and followed this tutorial to set up a login page using Vaadin Flow and Spring Security: https://vaadin.com/docs/v22/flow/tutorial/login-and-authentication

This works perfectly and checks login attempts against an `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` having a dummy user. As you can see in the tutorial, this is configured in the `WebSecurity` class, which extends `VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Now, I want to authenticate against Firebase users with email address and password instead. Therefore, I set up a Firebase project and added a user. I first thought, that the login can be done using the Firebase Admin SDK, but now I think this is not possible.

How can I authenticate Firebase users with email address and password in my Spring Boot application using Vaadin Flow as a frontend framework?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has two types of SDKs:

- Its regular SDKs are designed to be used in client-side, untrusted environments, such as web front-ends, Android apps, or iOS apps.
- Its [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) are designed to be used in (typically server-side), trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

Only the regular, client-side SDKs have methods to sign the user in. For the Admin SDKs this is not needed, since they already run in a trusted environment and this establish their credentials in some other way (typically through a credentials file that you download from the Firebase/Cloud console).

So there's no way to sign in to Firebase on your server-side code. This also would not make a lot of sense, because a lot of users will likely be accessing the server at once, so who is the current user?

Instead, in Firebase you typically sign the use in client-side through one of the regular SDKs, and then (if needed) you pass the ID token to the server, where your code (through an Admin SDK if available) can [decode that ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and determine what user is making the request.

You *can* [mint your own ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) in the Admin SDK, but the flow remains the same there and you typically use this to implement a custom sign-in provider.

Comment: So I need to use the JS API and put this into a custom Vaadin component to handle sign ins: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth ... It would be nice if someone shared such an integration.

Comment: There is still the Vaadin Flow integration of the Firebase sign in. I will figure out it on my own, if no one shares an example and come back to here later.